# this.state is not an object when inside a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, this

I have the following function within a function and Im trying to check the state of an object. The problem is that when I run the code it is telling me that this.state is not an object.

```
convertNeighbourArrayIntoMap(neighbourData) {

        var neighbourCategoryMap = {}; // Create the blank map

        neighbourData.forEach(function(neighbourItem) {

            if(this.state.searchString == ""){
               console.log("No Search String");
            }

            if (!neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category]) {
              // Create an entry in the map for the category if it hasn't yet been created
              neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category] = [];
            }

            neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category].push(neighbourItem);

        });

        return neighbourCategoryMap;  
    }
```

This works but I need it to be inside the loop.

```
convertNeighbourArrayIntoMap(neighbourData) {

        var neighbourCategoryMap = {}; // Create the blank map

if(this.state.searchString == ""){
               console.log("No Search String");
            }

        neighbourData.forEach(function(neighbourItem) {

            if (!neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category]) {
              // Create an entry in the map for the category if it hasn't yet been created
              neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category] = [];
            }

            neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category].push(neighbourItem);

        });

        return neighbourCategoryMap;  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `forEach`'s callback is not picking up the same context.  The easy fix it to switch to an arrow function (if possible):

```
       neighbourData.forEach((neighbourItem) => {

            if(this.state.searchString == ""){
               console.log("No Search String");
            }

            if (!neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category]) {
              // Create an entry in the map for the category if it hasn't yet been created
              neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category] = [];
            }

            neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category].push(neighbourItem);

        });
```

If you don't have arrow functions available, then `bind` the `forEach` function:

```
       neighbourData.forEach(function(neighbourItem) {

            if(this.state.searchString == ""){
               console.log("No Search String");
            }

            if (!neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category]) {
              // Create an entry in the map for the category if it hasn't yet been created
              neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category] = [];
            }

            neighbourCategoryMap[neighbourItem.category].push(neighbourItem);

        }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function to preserve `this` context as expected:

```
neighbourData.forEach((neighbourItem) => {
...
  if (!this.state.searchString.length) {
    console.log("No Search String");
  }
...
```